# Calculate average of list with hh:mm format

Tags: python, python-2.7, time

I have a list with multiple times, with this time format: `hour:minutes`

```
[u'04:20', u'03:00', u'03:40']
```

Now I need to calculate the average time for this list. The first idea that comes to my mind is just convert the list to something like:

```
a = [04.20, 03.00, 03.40] 

total = 0.0
for i in a:
    total += i

print total / len(a) #3.53333333333
#or `sum(a)/len(a)`
```

There is a better way of doing that? I mean, without convert the list.

Comment: What's the average of `00:00` and `12:00`?

Comment: @orlp 00:00 does not exist in list. at least 00:01 is required

Comment: You're dodging the issue. What's the average of `00:01` and `12:01`?

Comment: @orlp I don't understand what is the problem http://codepad.org/OKEtwxgT

Comment: @anvd Why not `18:01`?

Comment: @orlp Because the user chooses from 00-08 h and 00-50 minutes. that's why.

Comment: @anvd: What's halfway between 2:30 and 3:30? Your method is `(2.30 + 3.30) / 2`, which gives 2:80. Is this what you want, or do you see a problem there?

Comment: @Marius, ok, in that case i have a problem. thanks for clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the time as a duration or the time it takes to perform a task then it would probably read better.

You can't convert straight to decimal because there are 60 minutes in an hour and not 100. What you could do is convert everything to minutes and then work out the average. Something like this:

```
times = [u'04:20', u'03:00', u'03:40']
to_min = lambda t: int(t.split(':')[0])*60 + int(t.split(':')[1])
to_hr = lambda m: '%02d:%02d' % ((m - m%60)/60, m%60)
average = to_hr(sum([to_min(t) for t in times])/len(times))
print average
# 03:40
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you did it won't work because minutes are base-60, not base-100. I would recommend breaking the hours/minutes apart first. For example: `["04:20", "03:00", "03:40"]` would be converted to `[(4, 20), (3, 0), (3, 40)]`. You can then get the average from the minutes and hours separately and recombine the result.

Answer (score 0):

Search for a package that supports a date/time format; there are several.
Failing that, make sure you convert accurately -- your example has the wrong answer.  You need to recognize that the minutes are in base 60, not 100.

Also, note that there's a nice "avg" function.